# Module 'AudioKit' has no member named 'inputDevices'

Tags: audiokit

This is my whole application so far, using AudioKit 4 and the documentation and AudioKit's website:

```
import SwiftUI
import AudioKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(content: {
            Button("test", action: {
                if let inputs = AudioKit.inputDevices {
                    try! AudioKit.setInputDevice(inputs[0])
                }
            }).padding()
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The line `AudioKit.inputDevices` fails with:

```
Module 'AudioKit' has no member named 'inputDevices'
```

I searched and found that I should (apparently) be using AudioKit 5, and `AudioEngine`. Ok, here goes:

```
                if let inputs = AudioEngine.inputDevices {
                    let device: AudioKit.Device = inputs[0]
                    try! AudioEngine.setInputDevice(device)
                }
```

That fails with:

```
Module 'AudioEngine' has no member named 'setInputDevice'
```

Looking, there is apparently only `setDevice` and it is for the output device.

Why does the documentation suggest that there is a `setInputDevice` function?

I have tried the latest version 4, as well as version 5, both releases.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Use `AKManager` instead of `AudioKit`
I can't tell why they changed it but it was a few versions ago.